# Get current system time in R

Tags: r, datetime

How do I get the current system time in R?
For example, when using `Sys.time()`
I get something like this:
`2021-04-14 13:04:27`
But I only want the time part  `13:04:27`

Comment: Use `format(Sys.time(), '%T')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with this code:

```
format(Sys.time(), "%H:%M:%S")
```